# Error when finalizing and summing the results

Tags: python

I'm studying introduction to programming and the language used is Python, I have the following algorithm below and I wanted some help to understand where the error is, I put the login and password correctly, I type the code of two products that are in the table and the value that appears is much higher than it should be, but if I just type a product code, the algorithm shows me the correct value

```
x = 0
acum = 0
acum2 = 0
soma = 0
cod = 1

while x <= 2:
 login = str(input("Enter login: "))
 password = int(input("Password: "))
 x = x + 1
 if login != 'ifpe' or password != 12345:
    print("Invalid login and/or password.")
 if x > 2:
    print("Attempts exceeded!")
    break
if login == 'ifpe' and password == 12345:
    while cod != 0:
        print("|  Code   |   Product       | Price (R$) |")
        print("|   100   | Hot dog         |    1,70    |")
        print("|   101   | Simple Bauru    |    2,30    |")
        print("|   102   | Bauru with egg  |    2,60    |")
        print("|   103   | Hambúrguer      |    2,40    |")
        print("|    0    |     Exit        |")
        print()
        cod = int(input("Enter product code: "))
        qnt = int(input("Enter the amount: "))
        acum2 = acum2 + qnt
        if cod == 0:
            break
        if cod == 100:
            soma = 1.70 * qnt
            acum += 1
        else:
            if cod == 101:
                soma = 2.30 * qnt
                acum += 1
            else:
                if cod == 102:
                    soma = 2.60 * qnt
                    acum += 1
                else:
                    if cod == 103:
                        soma = 2.40 * qnt
                        acum += 1
    print("Completed\nTotal: ", soma * acum)
    break
```

So far we've only learned how to use if and while, so I can't use anything else to improve the algorithm.

Comment: But what is the error?

Comment: maybe I said it wrong, so it's the following: if I type for example the code 100 and in `qnt` type the value 5, type the code 101 and in `qnt` type 5 too, the value will be 23 and not 20 as it should be

Comment: What is `soma`, in the next to last line?

Comment: Two general tips: 1. Always indent by four spaces. 2. Never use `sum` as a variable name. It's an in-built function in Python.

Comment: my algorithm is in portuguese and i changed the words to english to be able to ask for help here. the word `sum` is the same thing as `sum`  , it's the name in Portuguese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During each iteration of the `while cod != 0:` loop, the value of `soma` is overwritten. So in the end, when you print `soma * acum`, you are only using the value from the last iteration, that is, for the last product that was selected.

Instead, you could keep track of the current total within the loop:

```py
curr_total = 0

while cod != 0:
    
    # calculate soma the way you did
    
    curr_total = curr_total + soma

print("Completed\nTotal: ", curr_total)
```

That way, you may not even need the `acum` count.